# Unable to make the html of the data in the controller and show on the dropdown select

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

i want to show the restaurant after selecting its area from dropdown list. but my code did not show the restaurant name and the menu button  of that restaurant please tell me where i did mistake

This is  my view code

```
    <div id="restaurant">


    </div>
```

This is controller code

```
     public function get_rests()
    {

        $cit_id = $this->input->post('cit_id');
        $area = $this->input->post('areaID');
        $where = array('city_id'=>$cit_id,'city_area_id'=>$area);


        $html = '

        <div class="container" id="">


            <table align="centre" class="table table-condensed table-striped table-hover no-margin"style="width:70%" id="">

                <thread>

                    <tr style="width: 56%;">
                        <th>
                            No.

                        </th>
                        <th style="">
                            Restaurant Names
                        </th>
                    </tr>

                </thread>
                <tbody>

                <?php $i=1;foreach($result as $row){
                    ?>

                    <tr id="<?php echo $row->restaurant_id; ?>" class="res_id">
                        <th style="">
                            <?php echo  $i++; ?>

                        </th>
                        <th style="">
                            <?php echo $row->restaurant_name; ?>




                        </th>

                        <th style="width: 1%" >
                            <a href="<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/BulkRecipe_Controller/bulk_recipe/<?php echo $row->restaurant_id;?>"  class="btn btn-warning" <i class="glyphicon-edit"></i>See Menu</a>

                        </th>
                    </tr>
                <?php } ?>

                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>

        ';
        echo $html;
```

This is my model code view

```
function select_record($table, $where = NULL){

    $this->db->select();
    if($where)
        $this->db->where($where);
    $this->db->from($table);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    //  echo $this->db->last_query();
    return $query->result();
}
```

Script code

```
 function get_rests(){

        var city_id = $('#city_id').val();
        var area_id = $("#area_id").val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "<?=base_url();?>index.php/Bulk_Controller/get_rests",
            data: {cit_id: city_id,areaID: area_id},
            dataType: "text",
            cache:false,
            success:
                function(data){
                    // alert(data);
                    $('#restaurant').html(data);
                }
        });
    }
```

Comment: do you get a response from the ajax and how does it looks like? is the js code on the same domain like the php code. i am asking to sort out any cors issues. Where does the select_record() gets called, also the php code you return in the $html string will never get executed.

Comment: what response do you get back from the Ajax call?

Comment: @hydre in ajax response whole view code show in response which is written in the controller.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't called a model function to get data from your DB Table.

```
public function get_rests()
{

    $cit_id = $this->input->post('cit_id');
    $area = $this->input->post('areaID');
    $where = array('city_id'=>$cit_id,'city_area_id'=>$area);

    $result= $this->your_model->select_record('table_name',$where);
    $html = '

    <div class="container" id="">


        <table align="centre" class="table table-condensed table-striped table-hover no-margin"style="width:70%" id="">

            <thread>

                <tr style="width: 56%;">
                    <th>
                        No.

                    </th>
                    <th style="">
                        Restaurant Names
                    </th>
                </tr>

            </thread>
            <tbody>

            <?php $i=1;foreach($result as $row){
                ?>

                <tr id="<?php echo $row->restaurant_id; ?>" class="res_id">
                    <th style="">
                        <?php echo  $i++; ?>

                    </th>
                    <th style="">
                        <?php echo $row->restaurant_name; ?>




                    </th>

                    <th style="width: 1%" >
                        <a href="<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/BulkRecipe_Controller/bulk_recipe/<?php echo $row->restaurant_id;?>"  class="btn btn-warning" <i class="glyphicon-edit"></i>See Menu</a>

                    </th>
                </tr>
            <?php } ?>

            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>

    ';
    echo $html;
```